# django returns blank /empty string as None

Tags: python, django, types

Django app is displaying  'None' value in the text field, if the database (postgres) return empty string.

Any idea, how could i display empty string? any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how big the application is, but if it's not too much of a hassle you can just update the models that have `"None"`.

Something like:

`ModelA.objects.filter(the_field="None").update(the_field=None)
ModelB.objects.filter(another_field="None").update(another_field=None)`

If there are too many fields to do manually, you could iterate through each field in the model to do the filter:

```
for field in ModelA._meta.get_all_field_names():
    try:
        d = {field: "None"}
        ModelA.objects.filter(**d).update(**{field: None})
    except:
        pass
```